# How to access gridview from one .cs file to another .cs file in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one gridview in a windows forms. I have `checkData.cs`,`myNames.cs` files. 
I divided some functions and kept these functions in these .cs files.
All files has the namespace `myNameSpace` 
Program.cs file has the gridview. When I am trying to access that gridview from checkData.cs it is showing an error as `The data dataGridView1 doesnot exist in the current context`.
How to access the grid view?

in Program.cs I have following code

```
namespace myNameSpace
{

    class Program : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    }
}
```

in checkData.cs file I am trying to access that gridview as follows.

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
 public BindToGrid()
{
dataGridView1.dataSource = mySource; //assume that mySource has grid bound data
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to make the classes in your `checkData.cs` and `myNames.cs` files take the `DataGridView` as a constructor parameter.  Something like:

```
public class CheckData 
{
   public CheckData(DataGridView Gridview)
   {
       _gridView = GridView;
   }

   private readonly DataGridView _gridView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `DataGridView` to the other class as a parameter and store a reference to it (classes are reference type in C#, so it's pretty straight forward.)

EDIT: Coding Gorilla's answer shows it.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace isn't terribly important here. I'm not sure if your classes and/or methods in checkData.cs and myNames.cs are static or not, but the DataGridView object you have resides as a child of you forms object. In order to access this object, it must be passed into the class or method you want to access it from. One way to do it would be to pass it into a constructor. Another way is to have a property in your class. Personally I think it would be more useful to have any methods that need to have access to this object to be passed in directly as a parameter.

Alternatively, if what you're doing affects the data of the DataGridView and you're just trying to keep your logic external to the form itself, then you could put the logic in an extension method and simply call it directly from within your form.

From inside the form:

```
using MyExtensions; 

...

private void MyMethod()
{
    this.DataGridView1.CheckNames();
}
```

Then create an extensions class with the CheckNames method (Extensions.cs or something):

```
public static class Extensions
{

    public static void CheckNames(this DataGridView source)
    {
        // Do  your logic here.
    }

}
```

I find extension methods to be extremely handy in separating/reusing logic that is tied to specific classes. Here is [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).